# Anaconda Prompt command line commands

Tags: command-line, anaconda

I recently started using Anaconda Prompt instead of the Windows CLI. I note that standard CLI commands like 'cd' to change directory work in Anaconda Prompt, but other standard commands like 'ls' do not work.
How can I list the contents in a directory in Anaconda prompt? Do I have to import the os module or can I do this directly?
Thanks

Comment: On Windows, the standard command to list the files in a directory is `dir`, not `ls`

Answer (score 19):

Anaconda Prompt takes most or all of the commands that Command Prompt takes, plus many that are unique to Conda, which you can both access introductions to and start further exploration of [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/#anaconda-navigator-or-conda).

But as darthbith commented, you need to use `dir`, not `ls`, in Command Prompt and its derivatives.

Answer (score 11):

You can use 'dir' instead of 'ls' to list directories and files. In case you prefer Linux commands, install the package below in your Anaconda Prompt, then you can use basic Linux commands as well:

```
conda install m2-base
```